# How do window managers set the background of the root window

Tags: x11, xlib

I am trying to learn xlib, but I couldn’t find any function that lets me set the background of the root window. How do window managers, or tools like feh, manage the desktop wallpaper? I have tried the XSetWindowBackground function, but that only seems to work with top level windows.

Comment: I haven't used `XSetWindowBackground`, but `XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap` can certainly set the desktop wallpaper. You need to `XClearWindow` and `XCloseDisplay` for it to take effect.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by “you need to XClearWindow and XCloseDisplay for it to take effect”? How does the wm manage windows if it called XCloseDisplay?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at my set background code, which does not need to run after setting the window background. You will of course need to clear the window to force it to repaint. The WM should not be involved with setting the window background, unless it is doing something clever to implement transparency, in which case, the `XSetWindowBackground` will not work.